# Test bash command line arguments

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I don't know bash well but this seems pretty basic, yet I'm stuck on it. I'm using the bash installed on Mac OS X. I'm simply trying to test 1 command line argument and this is what I have and it doesn't work.

```
if [$1 -eq 'clean']
then
    echo "Your argument is 'clean'!"
fi
```

Every time I've tried it, bash gives me a command not found error.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, what is it?

Comment: Spaces around `[` and `]` are required so use: `if [ "$1" = 'clean' ]`

Comment: Thanks! If you post it as an answer and correct the single equal sign with a double equal sign, I will approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues here:

1. Spaces around `[` and `]` are required in shell
2. `-eq` is used for comparing integers not for strings

Try this instead:

```
if [[ "$1" == "clean" ]]; then
    echo "Your argument is 'clean'!"
fi
```

If you are using bash then `[[` and `]]` are more efficient than `[ and ]`